# WSO2-IS behind a reverse proxy

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use WSO2 Identity Server behind a reverse proxy to not expose ip and port when I use wso2 custom pages like "Create Password" and "Reset Password", but I'm getting an error.

When I try to log in on carbon it redirect to login_action.jsp and it shows:

**login_action.jsp - 403 Forbidden.**

The steps that I did to configure were:
deployment.toml

```
[server]
offset = "1"
hostname = "example.com"
node_ip = "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx"
base_path = "https://$ref{server.hostname}:${carbon.management.port}"
proxy_context_path = "/is"

[transport.https.properties] 
proxyPort = 443
```

nginx.conf

```
server {

    server_name example.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/dev_mtz_access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com.error_log debug;

    proxy_cache one;
    proxy_cache_key $request_method$request_uri;
    proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
    proxy_cache_methods GET;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 1y;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/certs/cup.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/private/cup.key;

    rewrite \w*(carbon|admin)$ $1/ permanent;

     location /is/ {
        proxy_pass                            https://csm-wso2-is:9444/;
        proxy_redirect                        https://example.com/authenticationendpoint/ https://example.com/is/authenticationendpoint/;
        proxy_redirect                        https://example.com/accountrecoveryendpoint/ https://example.com/is/accountrecoveryendpoint/;
        proxy_redirect                        https://example.com/oauth2/ https://example.com/is/oauth2/;
        proxy_redirect                        https://example.com/carbon/ https://example.com/is/carbon/;
        proxy_http_version                    1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass                    $http_upgrade;
        # Proxy headers
        proxy_set_header Upgrade              $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection           "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host                 $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server   $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host     $host;
        # Proxy timeouts
        proxy_connect_timeout                 3600s;
        proxy_send_timeout                    3600s;
        proxy_read_timeout                    3600s;
      } 

      location /carbon/admin/js/csrfPrevention.js {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host               $http_host;
       proxy_read_timeout                  5m;
       proxy_send_timeout                  5m;
       proxy_pass                          https://example.com/is/carbon/admin/js/csrfPrevention.js;

       proxy_http_version                  1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade            $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection         "upgrade";
      }
```

I didn't find any documentation explaining how to achieve, only on WSO2-APIM

Comment: Do you want to add the subcontext `/is`?

Comment: Yes, because I have other contexts on this reverse proxy to others microservices.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a subcontext the easiest way is to route everything coming to the root context (`/`) to port 9443. Here is a sample Nginx config block.

```
upstream ssl.wso2.is.com {
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xx3:9443;
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xx4:9443;
    ip_hash;
}

server {
listen 443;
    server_name is.wso2.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/wrk.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/wrk.key;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_read_timeout 5m;
            proxy_send_timeout 5m;
            proxy_pass https://ssl.wso2.is.com;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
}
```

The documentation is [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/front-with-the-nginx-load-balancer/#!).

Comment: My default `location /` is to a React App.